# Show that there is precisely one cyclic code C of length 8 and dimension 3. Write down a generator matrix for C.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cyclic-groups, coding-theory

I am a little lost in regards to handle this question. I am aware that a cyclic code of size $[n=8,k=3]$ must have a generator polynomial $g(x)$ of degree $n-k$ which equates to $8-3=5$ in this case. Also it must be a factor of $x^8+1$.

We are working in GF(2) however so I use maple to factor and gain:

$1+x^8 = (1+x^4)^2=(1+x)^8$.

Niether of these are of degree $5$ so I feel as though I may have misunderstood something.

I *think* the generator matrix should be:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $

But this is based on finding $g(x)=1+x+x^3$. I'm not sure if that is what I should be finding here and if so, how to go about it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: $1+x+x^3$ has no common factors with $1+x^8$, so it will generate a trivial cyclic code (all eight cyclic shifts are linearly independent, and you get $k=8$). It is a factor of $1+x^7$, but that doesn't help here.

Comment: HINT: $$1+x^8=(1+x)^8=(1+x)^3(1+x)^5$$ has a unique factor of degree five.